# Is a calling a temporary ban as such a misnomer?

Tags: meaning

During a [recent moderation procedure](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11828/did-i-incorrectly-flag-these-posts), I used the phrase:

> I'm currently flag-banned

To describe a one week period of inability to use post flags. We discussed the situations several times in different places. Eventually, some users argued that calling it a "ban" would be a misnomer as it functions as a suspension. I believe that using the phrase as I did, is appropriate and not a misnomer — it comes with a different connotation that suspension doesn't carry, but my phrasing seems entirely correct.

Comment: _[ban] comes with a different connotation that suspension doesn't carry..._ which is what?

Comment: Just because ***suspension*** implies "limited duration" doesn't mean ***ban*** only works if "permanent" is implied.

Comment: @KillingTime in this specific context a ban sounds like a stronger sanction while a suspension sounds softer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree.

Comment: The term "ban" had various historical meanings, some of which were more or less permanent (e.g. excommunication or declaration of outlawry). But that doesn't mean the modern sense requires a permanent ban, and you'll see lots of examples of short bans if you google e.g. "one month ban".

Comment: @StuartF That matches my assumptions, thanks.

Comment: This is easily researched. Over 1m Google hits for "temporary ban", including [Collins Dictionary.com ... 'temporary ban'](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/temporary-ban0).

Comment: Why was this closed as opinion-based?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/conversation/ban-misnomer context from chat.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If it is incorrect, it would be a misnomer - I suppose that was where I came from — For instance, if the "temoprary" was necessary to indicate the meaning.

Comment: 'Temporary ban', licensed by Collins, indicates that some if not all bans are non-permanent. The correct closure reason here is that this is easily researched, too basic for ELU. // If some institution has a stipulative definition for 'ban' that includes a 'mandatorily permanent' caveat, that would not be everyday usage, and would be off-topic on ELU.